# LoadFromXaml parse exception inflating MenuBarItem

Tags: xaml, maui

When I try to use the method to inflate my XAML:

```
MenuBarItem item = new().LoadFromXaml("<MenuBarItem Text=\"Session\"><MenuFlyoutItem Text=\"New\"/><MenuFlyoutItem Text=\"Save\"/><MenuFlyoutItem Text=\"Load\"/></MenuBarItem>");
```

the MenuBarItem is created and Text properly assigned but all the MenuFlyoutItems are ommited and not added to the menu.

After reading [Load XAML at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/runtime-load?view=net-maui-7.0) documentation and particularly the "The LoadFromXaml method can be used to inflate any XAML" and the examples given, I assumed that I can throw any valid XAML into it - from a single button, to a DataTemplate of a ListView, a MenuBarItem for a menu, to a whole ContentPage and it should work. But it's not working in this case - I get Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParseException and System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException.

Is this behavior a bug or is documentation missing some details about loading XAMLs?

When I enclose the MenuBarItem in a ContentPage's MenuBarItems like this:

```
new ContentPage().LoadFromXaml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<ContentPage\r\n\txmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui\"\r\n\txmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml\"\r\n\tx:Class=\"LoadRuntimeXAML.CatalogItemsPage\"\r\n\tTitle=\"Catalog Items\">\r\n\t<ContentPage.MenuBarItems>\r\n\t\t<MenuBarItem Text=\"Session\">\r\n\t\t\t<MenuFlyoutItem\r\n\t\t\t\tText=\"New\"/>\r\n\t\t\t<MenuFlyoutItem\r\n\t\t\t\tText=\"Save\"/>\r\n\t\t\t<MenuFlyoutItem\r\n\t\t\t\tText=\"Load\"/>\r\n\t\t</MenuBarItem>\r\n\t</ContentPage.MenuBarItems>\r\n</ContentPage>");
```

it inflates without error and then when I assign elements from the inflated ContentPage to the MainPage's MenuBarItems they display well. But this is an ugly workaround because I don't need a whole ContentPage, just the MenuBarItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XAML is not complete, thus cannot be parsed.

What the ContentPage has, that your XAML lacks, is the various `xmlns` lines, that specify the XML elements used in the XAML.

I have not tested, but try replacing `<MenuBarItem` with

```xml
<MenuBarItem\r\n\txmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui\"\r\n\txmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml\"\r\n
```

Adapt as needed. Any whitespace can be used anywhere `\r\n` is shown.

If it doesn't work, also prefix with:
`<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n`

But I believe that is optional.

---

As an aside, anything that can be done in XAML, can instead be done in C#. [C# markup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/markup/markup).

C#, being a complete computational language, can often create dynamic UI more easily than XAML, if you are building a UI that depends on different conditions.

A convenient approach in C#, is to define "helper" methods, that take whatever parameters you want, and creates a specific element. That you add to a given parent element, either via C# markup, or methods of a parent layout class.

Its easy to write helper methods that call other helper methods, to build up a whole layout to your specs, controlled at each step by the parameters that matter to you.

At the top level, you might end up with code like this:

```cs
// use custom helper methods and methods of "Grid" class.
Grid grid = MyCreateGrid();
grid.Children.Add(MyCreateRowLabel(text), 1, 0);
grid.Children.Add(
    // OR use C# markup
    new StackLayout
    {
      Children =
      {
        new Label().Text("Code:"),
        ...
      }
    },
    1, 1
);
...
```

Comment: Thank you, the xmlns was what I was missing. The example with the button in the docs is misleading - it does not say anywhere that it works just for the one element without the xmlsn.

Comment: Also thanks for the side note. I know I can create all the UI elements in C#. It just happens that I have to send them through the network and it is easier (in my opinion at least, maybe I'm wrong) to send a XAML and parse it than send a bunch of instructions in lists or dicts to recrate the UI using C#.

Comment: Excellent point. I agree: if it isn't hardcoded at compile time, XAML is more convenient than C#.

Answer (score 0):

From the official document, it's only using LoadFromXaml for single view or a complete contentPage. I also tried LoadFromXaml for `<MenuBarItem Text=\"Session\"><MenuFlyoutItem Text=\"New\"/><MenuFlyoutItem Text=\"Save\"/><MenuFlyoutItem Text=\"Load\"/></MenuBarItem>`, and just you said that:

> the MenuBarItem is created and Text properly assigned but all the MenuFlyoutItems are ommited and not added to the menu.

But you can achieve it by doing this:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp_loadXaml.MainPage"
             x:Name="contentPage">

   <Button Text="click" Clicked="Button_Clicked" HeightRequest="50"/>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var xaml = "<MenuBarItem Text=\"Session\"></MenuBarItem>";
        var xaml1 = "<MenuFlyoutItem Text=\"New\"/>";
        var xaml2 = "<MenuFlyoutItem Text=\"Save\"/>";
        var xaml3 = "<MenuFlyoutItem Text=\"Load\"/>";

        MenuFlyoutItem menuFlyoutItem_1 = new MenuFlyoutItem().LoadFromXaml(xaml1);
        MenuFlyoutItem menuFlyoutItem_2 = new MenuFlyoutItem().LoadFromXaml(xaml2);
        MenuFlyoutItem menuFlyoutItem_3 = new MenuFlyoutItem().LoadFromXaml(xaml3);
        MenuBarItem item = new MenuBarItem();
        item.LoadFromXaml(xaml);

        item.Add(menuFlyoutItem_1);
        item.Add(menuFlyoutItem_2);
        item.Add(menuFlyoutItem_3);

       contentPage.MenuBarItems.Add(item);
    }
```

It works well.

Comment: Yes, I know I could do it in C# but I have to send the UI through the network (I forgot to mention that in my question) and I think it is easier to send a XAML string and parse it.